# How to detect multi page PDF through PHP or imagemagick?

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

For instance, when I uploaded a file to the temp folder on server,  are there any way to scan through the folder and check whether a specific file is multi page or not?

Some code like:

```
$files = scandir ('$tempSrc');
foreach ($files as $pdf) {
    $isMulti = //exec some command or call php function (if any?);
    echo $isMulti;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php php class.

```
$files = scandir ('$tempSrc');
foreach ($files as $pdf) {
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->pingImage($pdf);
    echo $isMulti = ($im->getNumberImages() > 1) ? true : false;
}
```